# Personnalized Microsoft Teams connector config page

Tags: microsoft-teams, office365connectors

#### Question

> How can I make my **Microsoft Teams connector config page** look like the ones bellow?

#### Details

I'm creating a teams app with a connector. The documentation explain how to make our own config page. (for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msteams-webhooks-connectors/7-exercise-o365-connectors) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/connectors-creating#example-manifestjson-with-connector#integrating-the-configuration-experience)). It works for me .

But in the app directory, I saw multiple existing connectors that share the same config page structure. (name of connector, then webhook, then instructions to install)

This structure would be good for me but I did not found how to configure my connector to use that template.

Thanks for help .

[image]

Comment: You can configure your connector page the way you want. Please take a look at the sample [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-connector-csharp/blob/master/TeamsToDoAppConnector/Views/Connector/Setup.cshtml). You can add your own configuration in the setup page.

Comment: Thanks Gousia for your comment. Indeed I can build it myself and it work good. But when I inspect their config page, it looks like there is another way to build that config page .

Comment: You can build the setup page in your own way. You could choose to give any kind of UI in the setup page.